# iis7 forms authentication is missing?

Tags: iis-7

I do not have the option for form Authentication in IIS Manager under IIS=>Authentication. I do have the following options:

1)Anonymous Authentication
2)ASP.NET Impersonation
3)basic Authentication

according to this, forms Authentication is needed to provide for an application

please help me to fix it.

Comment: When clicking on the site name in the left tree of IIS Manager do you see the three sections 'ASP.NET', 'IIS' and 'Management' in the middle?

Comment: @peter:yes it have 3 sections

Comment: hmm, open the file: C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\administration.config in the second block of the moduleProviders node, do you have a FormsAuthentication entry?

Comment: No, I couldn't find it in modules

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could try:

Make a backup of 'C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\administration.config'.

In

```
<moduleProviders>
```

find the line

```
<add name="Impersonation" type="Microsoft.Web...
```

and make a copy of it just below, then replace '**ImpersonationModuleProvider**' with '**FormsAuthenticationModuleProvider**' in the new line.

further down in the file in the section:

```
<location path=".">
    <modules>
```

check whether there is an entry:

```
<add name="FormsAuthentication" />
```

and if not, add it.

I don't know whether this will fix your problem or why these entries are missing in the first place. But it is worth a try.

Otherwise I would re-install IIS.